# Run time error 1004 on using Vlookup function

Tags: vba, excel, exception

Im trying to highlight range of cells when a date is present in the list of holidays. But on running the below code, the Run time error 1004 is displayed. I have even tried handling it in error handler; but it is not working. Can somebody please help me why this error is occuring and resolve the same?

```
Sub highlight_cells()
Dim myrange As Range
On Error GoTo myerr:
For i = 1 To 10
Set myrange = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(10, i))
temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(Cells(1, i)), [holidays], 2, False)
If (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(temp)) Then
myrange.Interior.Color = 3
End If
Next i

myerr:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
MsgBox "vlookup error"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `[holidays]` supposed to be? Is it a named range? Is that literally how your code is written? I assume your error occurs on the `temp = Application....` line?

Comment: holidays is the named list.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `holidays` then? no brackets on either side? Unless you have it literally named `[holidays]` (but I'm not sure if you can have brackets in a named range)

Comment: @BruceWayne brackets are an (ugly, to me) alternative to `Range`, so `[holidays]` equals `Range("holidays")`

Comment: If you have to use a named range in a vlookup, you have to specify it in square brackets. I have tried this in other examples and it has worked.

Comment: Instead of vlookup, perhaps try countif()?

Comment: Hi, sorry all these times I was referring to column 2 in vlookup. That was causing the problem. The list of holiday is a single column list. Hence vlookup was throwing error. ANd one more thing the named ranges work as I have entered and even the actual range also gives the same result.

Comment: By the way I wanted to know the difference between Application. Vlookup and APplication.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup? Can anybody explain about these please?

Answer (score 0):

`Range(Cells(1, i))` isn't a valid range reference

maybe you wanted to reference `Cells(1, i)`

furthermore you can exploit the `Application` `VLookup()` method that wraps the possible error in the returned variant variable that you can check with `IsError()` function like follows:

```
Dim temp As Variant
For i = 1 To 10
    Set myrange = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(10, i))
    temp = Application.VLookup(Cells(1, i), [holidays], 2, False)
    If Not IsError(temp) Then Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = 3
Next i
```

Comment: Now, im not getting the error. However, the vlookup fucntionality itself is not working properly now. Actually I want to highlight the cells when there is a match in vlookup. Even thought there are 5 such dates, vlookup is not highlighting any of those cells. Please note I just changed the If Not to If in my code. When I used the code as you have provided, all the cells highlighted which means that everytime vlookup is returning error.

Comment: you may want to post some shots of your data to see where `[holidays]` are and what cells are to be checked against that range

Comment: I think he just needs to do `holidays`, not `[holidays]`? Or am I missing something? But I agree, it'd help a lot to see a screen shot of what `[holidays]` is.  Also, @Madhu, replace `[holidays]` with the actual range and check if it works. If it does work, then it's an issue with the way the range is named, not necessarily the formula/VBA.

Comment: @BruceWayne, as for the "brackets" issue see my comment at OP

Comment: Right now im in office. Taking screen print has been disabled here. I will upload the screen once I reach home. Meanwhile I replaced the named range with the actual range and still the same problem exists.

Comment: in the meanwhile you may type ranges address here, and specify what format are dates input in there

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conditional formatting method, without using VBA.

Select your range > Conditional Formating > New Rule > Use a formula ...

Enter this formula

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,$J$2:$K$6,1,FALSE)
```

Take care of the "$" in the formula. This should highlight all cells that were found in the holidays list.

[image: Conditional Formatting V lookup]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wanted to do this in VBA not through excel formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay , It worked in Excel 2010 , Your problem is with VBA Error handling method.

Go to Tools --> Options -->General --> Error Trapping 
And check "Break on unhanded Errors"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry all these times I was referring to column 2 in vlookup. That was causing the problem. The list of holiday is a single column list. Hence vlookup was throwing error. ANd one more thing the named ranges work as I have entered and even the actual range also gives the same result.

Sub highlight_cells()
Dim myrange As Range

For i = 1 To 10

Set myrange = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(10, i))
MsgBox Cells(1, i)
temp = Application.VLookup(Cells(1, i), [holidays], 1, False)
If Not IsError(temp) Then
myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Next i

End Sub